# Cycle through imageview

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sleep, wait

I've got this code :

```
    public void createTask() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int color = rnd.nextInt(10);
        showImage(color);
    }
```

But I want it to cycle through the image-views.. so show one, keep it on the screen for 3 seconds, then show 2nd, keep that on screen for 3 seconds, show 3rd and so on.

I've made showImage and hideImage methods to keep code clean :

```
    public void showImage(int color) {
    ((ImageView) findViewById(myImagebtns[color]))
            .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
};
```

How should I program the waiting time (sleep? thread?) not locking the UI?

Comment: why dont you use only one ImageView and change its color? It is much simplier.  public void showImage(int color) { imageview.setBackgroundColor(color);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not block UI thread use a `Handler` with its `postDelayed` method.

```
int repeatCount = 0;
handler = new Handler();
runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        switchImage();
            Log.d("MSG", "repeatCount is : " + repeatCount);
            repeatCount ++;
            if(repeatCount < 5) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
```

I suggest you to use a single ImageView and switch its background color or image resource every 3 seconds. (Using `ImageView`s for every image will be a cost for your app.)

```
public void switchImage() {
    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView); 
    // TODO: get your image or color here and apply it to your single imageView
    // You may need an index while getting the next image or randomly get it.

    myImageView.setImageResource(getNextImageResId());
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to switch n times you can define a variable(such as repeatCount) and increment that variable. If you log out you'll see something like this(As you see every lines have 3 seconds difference):

```
11-11 20:17:19.909: D/MSG(1068): repeatCount is : 0
11-11 20:17:22.917: D/MSG(1068): repeatCount is : 1
11-11 20:17:25.921: D/MSG(1068): repeatCount is : 2
11-11 20:17:28.921: D/MSG(1068): repeatCount is : 3
11-11 20:17:31.925: D/MSG(1068): repeatCount is : 4
```

Comment: Ok. Implemented your method. I think that, if I want to switch 5 times, I call the method like this?

  for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
   myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, (2000*i));   
  }

Comment: No that'll cause 5 infinite loops. see my edited answer for your need.

Comment: I see, but your solution sets off 5 instances all at the same time? So there will be no 3 second delay between the 3rd and 4th?

Comment: I guess your question is answered?

Comment: Thanks aegaen. Not exactly. How do I pause the onCreate thread to wait for the 5th image shown and then move on?

Comment: That is a bad idea to pause onCreate(which means UIThread). Maybe you can call a method with an if statement inside the runnable(if(repeatCount == 4)) and call that method